# Changing redis filesystem writing behaviour

Tags: memory, database

The filesystem usage of redis is peaking every 20 minutes at the moment on my server. Sometimes from 63.1% to over 90.9%! This causes my monitoring to send me alerts if its over a longer time-frame. Is there a way to change the redis config so that this doesn't happen? Here is my current config:

```
activerehashing yes
appendfsync everysec
appendonly no
bind 127.0.0.1
daemonize yes
databases 16
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
loglevel notice
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
port 6379
rdbcompression yes
save 300 1000
save 60 80000
save 900 1
slave-serve-stale-data yes
syslog-enabled yes
timeout 300
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tune [these settings](http://redis.io/topics/persistence), now you have:

```
save 300 1000
save 60 80000
save 900 1
```

Explained:

```
save N M
```

means

> save redis dataset to disk every Ns if at least M keys changed

My advice is start with the default, which is `save 300 1000`. It is quite a reasonable setting. My guess is that on your machine these three saves accumulate somehow and then you see a pike.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly changing these values to the default doesn't fix the situation, the peaks are just getting wider but not smaller or less :(